# How to set divs to take percentage of remaining width

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have 7 divs of which I have several of fixed width, and the others should take a portion of remaining width.

Example:

```
<li>
    <div id="1">Should take 20%</div>
    <div id="2">Should take 30%</div>
    <div id="3" style="width:2em">Something</div>
    <div id="4" style="width:1em">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="5" style="width:2em">Something</div>
    <div id="6">Should take 30%</div>
    <div id="7">Should take 20%</div>
</li>
```

Okay, each div should have `display:inline-block;` or `display:table-cell;`.
Divs 1, 2, 6, 7 totalize 100% of the "remaining place", as 3, 4 and 5 will take a fixed width.

How could I achieve this ?

It is important that div id 7 takes the size until the right bound because the text should be aligned to the right.

Comment: you take already a 100% of the space. What remains? 0% i believe. I guess your div is taking advantage of your 0% already :D

Comment: If you want to keep the mark-up as is, you need JavaScript/jQuery.  If you can alter the HTML, then it may be possible.

Comment: This question makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach if you are willing to change the HTML mark-up.

Use `display: table` on the parent `.wrap` element and define three child cells, the left and right will have width 50%.  Each of these three child cells will contain a nested CSS table, `.cwrap`.

You can then use `display: table-cell` on the inner most elements and assign widths of 20% and 30% as needed.

The middle cell will adjust as needed depending on content.

```css
.wrap, .cwrap {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: table;
}
.c1 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
.c2 {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
.cc1 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
.cc2 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="c1">
    <div class="cwrap">
      <div class="cc1">Should take 20%</div>
      <div class="cc2">Should take 30%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="cwrap">
      <div class="cc3">Something</div>
      <div class="cc4">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="cc5">Something</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c1">
    <div class="cwrap">
      <div class="cc2">Should take 30%</div>
      <div class="cc1">Should take 20%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the best solution, say the one which is the most compatible with browsers!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/4d3c105L/

You can use http://caniuse.com/#search=calc like

```
width: calc((100% - 5em) * 0.2);
```

20 percent of (100 percent - 5em)

```
<li>
    <div id="1" class="w20" style="float:left">Should take 20%</div>
    <div id="2" class="w30" style="float:left">Should take 30%</div>
    <div id="3" style="float:left;width:2em;background-color:yellow;">Something</div>
    <div id="4" style="float:left;width:1em;background-color:orange;">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="5" style="float:left;width:2em;background-color:red;">Something</div>
    <div id="6" class="w30" style="float:left">Should take 30%</div>
    <div id="7" class="w20" style="float:left">Should take 20%</div>
</li>


.w20
{
    background-color:green;
    width: -moz-calc((100% - 5em) * 0.2);
    /* WebKit */
    width: -webkit-calc((100% - 5em) * 0.2);
    /* Opera */
    width: -o-calc((100% - 5em) * 0.2);
    /* Standard */
    width: calc((100% - 5em) * 0.2);
}


.w30
{
    background-color:blue;
    width: -moz-calc((100% - 5em) * 0.3);
    /* WebKit */
    width: -webkit-calc((100% - 5em) * 0.3);
    /* Opera */
    width: -o-calc((100% - 5em) * 0.3);
    /* Standard */
    width: calc((100% - 5em) * 0.3);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Thanks, this is an excellent solution I didn't know about. I just didn't check the "accept" check because I prefer to stay the most compatible using the solution with nested tables. But yours will for sure become my prefered solution in the future when browser support will improve and when we are sure IE8 is far enough! (Actually my company stays with IE8 because of business softwares, and I'm sure we're not the only ones ...)

Comment: @Sierramike My company has been ignoring IE 8 for a while now, some sources report ie8 is about 2% http://caniuse.com/usage_table.php but there are probably other resources that show ie8 as 10%. But yeah calc() is a very good solution.

Comment: @Sierramike Another one: https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<li id="outer">
     <div id="1"></div>
     <div id="2">Should take 30%</div>
     <div id="3" style="width:2em">Something</div>
     <div id="4" style="width:1em">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="5" style="width:2em">Something</div>
     <div id="6">Should take 30%</div>
     <div id="7">Should take 20%</div>
</li>
```

```css
#outer {
    min-width: 2000px; 
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
}

#1{
    width: 20%; 
    display:inline-block;
}
#2{
    width: 30%; 
    display:inline-block;
}
#3{
    width: 2em; 
    display:inline-block;
}

 #4{
    width: 1em; 
    display:inline-block;
}
#5{
    width: 2em; 
    display:inline-block;
 }
 #6{
    width: 30%; 
    display:inline-block;
 }
 #7{
    width: 20%; 
    display:inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the css `calc()` function.

Use it as follows:

Example: `calc(20% - 20px)`

This way you can use percentages and px/em to calculate width/height.

Further explanation [here](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc).